# Why do so many of our users have the same identicon?

Tags: support, bug, profile-page

Recently, Stack Exchange regenerated users' identicons for security purposes, which you can read about [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389123/were-regenerating-all-identicons).

It happened a few days ago, and it seems that a *bunch* of users on our site now have the same profile picture.

There are two sets. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZVNX.png) image is the profile picture for [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/661/hanugm), [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4038/triyugi-narayan-mani), [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/17931/krishna-varna), [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/499/mr-k), [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/19804/kanthri), [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/13206/anubhav-jha), [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/39/cheenbabes), [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/1014/srinivasacarya-dasa), and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/113/user3603546) user.

The second set is smaller, but [these](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/12176/fierce-lord) [two](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/8422/sakthi) users also have the [same profile picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCTY0.png).

Anyone know why? Is it a bug, or is it supposed to be that way? As far as I know, Identicons are supposed to be uniquely generated.

Comment: similar but possibly outdated question on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379303/997587

Comment: @user - that's useful. It _is_ a post-regeneration problem because some of these are high-rep users who once had distinct identicons; Buddhism.SE seems to have its own default, and it's probably an issue on other sites too. ([1](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/3551), [2](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/10950), [3](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/533)).I don't really understand enough about gravatar and stuff to figure it out, but I know you're active on meta and you can feel free to make your own post about it if you wish; it's bound to be more informed than mine.